# How to combine column and bar chart on same axis in Highcharts?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I need to recreate the following visualisation in Highcharts:

[image]

It's just a histogram, with a single value bar chart overlapped on the same X axis. All the histogram data is pre-aggregated so I feel like I can achieve this just by combining a column series with a bar series.

However, as you can see in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/aaduane/pen/xxyEzGr?editors=0010.

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  xAxis: { tickInterval: 50, endOnTick: true },
  yAxis: { max: 238, visible: false },
  series: [
    {
      type: "column",
      pointPlacement: "between",
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointInterval: 50,
      data: [
        ["0-50", 0],
        ["50-100", 0],
        ["100-150", 181],
        ["150-200", 238],
        ["200-250", 4],
        ["250-300", 1],
        ["300-350", 0],
        ["350-400", 0],
        ["400-450", 0],
        ["450-500", 0],
        ["500-550", 0],
        ["550-600", 0],
        ["600-650", 0]
      ],
      color: "#000000",
      opacity: 0.6
    },
    { type: "bar", data: [500], color: "red" }
  ]
});
```

If I try add 'bar' series to a 'column' series, Highcharts will just make everything a 'bar' or a 'column', instead of having both.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with Highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to achieve this. Here is the example config with the additional settings for axes:

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this,
          height = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(-10) - this.yAxis[0].toPixels(100),
          from = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(0),
          to = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(200),
          width = to - from,
          rectStart = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(100);
        if (!chart.rect) {
          chart.rect = chart.renderer.rect(from, rectStart, width, height)
            .attr({
              fill: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
              zIndex: 100
            }).add(chart.rects)
            .add()
        } else {
          chart.rect.attr({
            x: from,
            y: rectStart,
            width,
            height
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    offset: 20,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickInterval: 50,
    endOnTick: true,
  },
  yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
      color: 'grey',
      width: 1,
      value: 0
    }],
    max: 238,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: '',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: "column",
    pointPlacement: "between",
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    pointInterval: 50,
    data: [
      ["0-50", 0],
      ["50-100", 0],
      ["100-150", 181],
      ["150-200", 238],
      ["200-250", 4],
      ["250-300", 1],
      ["300-350", 0],
      ["350-400", 0],
      ["400-450", 0],
      ["450-500", 0],
      ["500-550", 0],
      ["550-600", 0],
      ["600-650", 0]
    ],
    color: "#000000",
    opacity: 0.6
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/swLvfa7k/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: Oh, that is very useful, thank you. I would never have thought of this approach.